# Showing that Sobolev spaces are Hilbert spaces?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

What (steps) do I need to show to show that Sobolev spaces

$$H_k(\Omega)$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$

are Hilbert spaces?

---

**Sobolev space:**

Sobolev space $H_k
(Ω)$ consists of all functions $u ∈ L_2
(Ω)$ for which the weak
partial derivative $∂^α u$ is in 
$L_2(Ω)$ whenever $α ∈ N_0^n$
and $|α| ≤ k$.

Additionally some definitions may equip this space with an inner product and a norm.

Comment: If you already proved it is a vector place with a defined norm, then you only need to show through some dense set that it is complete.

Comment: @JonesY I'm given the definition of Sobolev space with an inner product as well as a norm. By reading something about Hilbert space (this is my first time reading about Sobolev/Hilbert spaces), I believe that 1) Completeness and 2) Having an inner product are enough for a space to be Hilbert. Right?

Comment: @mavivilj Yes, If you have it defined as a vector space with a norm. the only thing u need to show is completeness.

Comment: @JonesY What about the inner product?

Comment: The inner product is only used to define the norm. If you have the definition as a vector space with a norm you can retrieve the inner product

Comment: You need that the norm is induced by an inner product. Where would then be the distinction to banach spaces?